# Why is my code working if I call a function on a line before the line I defined the function on?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a mini-project for school. I tried to call a function I had already defined. It worked but the thing is that I called the function on line 40 for example and the function definition was on line 56. Why is it working? Is it because the whole compiler and interpreter thingy?

I am using PyCharm in script mode.

```
def game_intro():

print "------------------ First Hero ------------------"
global n1
n1 = raw_input("Please Type a Name for Your Hero: ")

while not valid_name(n1):
    print "------------------ First Hero ------------------"
    n1 = raw_input("Please Type a Name for Your Hero: ")

print "------------------ Second Hero ------------------"
global n2
n2 = raw_input("Please Type a Name for Your Hero: ")

while not valid_name(n2):
    print "------------------ Second Hero ------------------"
    n2 = raw_input("Please Type a Name for Your Hero: ")
while not no_repeat(n2):
    n2 = raw_input("Please Type a Name for Your Hero: ")





def valid_name(n):

if n == " ":   # TO AVOID THE PLAYER GIVING A NAME AS SPACE

    print "Your name can't be empty"
    return False

elif n == "":
    return False
return True




def no_repeat(m):  # TO MAKE SURE THE PLAYERS WON'T TAKE THE SAME NAME

if m == n1:

    print m + " Already Assigned, Please Type a Different Name."

    return False

return True
```

Comment: How can we know what line 40 or 56 is if you don't post the code...

Comment: @Miket25 I think his question is pretty general: why can I call a function before I define it?

Comment: Your function definitions are before your `main()` function is called or `if __name__` piece. Your code isn't running top to bottom line by line

Comment: Presumably because you *postponed execution* of line 40. If line 40 is itself inside a function, that code won't be executed until you call the function. As long as the `def function..` lines later on run *first*, it doesn't matter where in the source code it is placed.

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps, but I always hate making assumptions . Better to know exactly to be safe.

Comment: Still, a [mcve] would be preferred. Less than 10 lines can reproduce the problem

Comment: @Miket25 Well, the title also says it.

Comment: @KayV Yes, your initial suspicion is correct. `valid_name` needs to be defined before `game_intro` if `game_intro` is to call `valid_name`.

Comment: This code produces some error on my computer – "Indentation" something something.

Comment: Your code is fine. It's just not indented. Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have forgotten to indent the code inside your functions.

You should also add a `if __name__ == '__main__'` line so that you can run your code like a script:

`python test.py`

Try the following code:

`test.py`

```
def game_intro():

    print "------------------ First Hero ------------------"
    global n1
    n1 = raw_input("Please Type a Name for Your Hero: ")

    while not valid_name(n1):
        print "------------------ First Hero ------------------"
        n1 = raw_input("Please Type a Name for Your Hero: ")

    print "------------------ Second Hero ------------------"
    global n2
    n2 = raw_input("Please Type a Name for Your Hero: ")

    while not valid_name(n2):
        print "------------------ Second Hero ------------------"
        n2 = raw_input("Please Type a Name for Your Hero: ")
    while not no_repeat(n2):
        n2 = raw_input("Please Type a Name for Your Hero: ")


def valid_name(n):

    if n == " ":   # TO AVOID THE PLAYER GIVING A NAME AS SPACE

        print "Your name can't be empty"
        return False

    elif n == "":
        return False
    return True


def no_repeat(m):  # TO MAKE SURE THE PLAYERS WON'T TAKE THE SAME NAME

    if m == n1:

        print m + " Already Assigned, Please Type a Different Name."

        return False

    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game_intro()
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer on how to call functions without worrying about order is by using if __name__ == "__main__" e.g.

```
def fun2():
   pass
def fun1():
   pass

if __name__ == "__main__"
    func1()
    func2()
```

as mentioned already. But if I were you I would use classes to have full control. I would do something like:

```
import random
class Hero:
    def __init__(self):
        # Game Intro
        print('-'*18,'First Hero','-'*18)
        # First Hero
        while True:
            n1 = input('Type  Your Hero\'s name: ')
            # For beauty and rejecting Jim, jim
            self.n1 = n1.capitalize()
            if self.n1.split():
                break
            print('Invalid Hero\'s name\n')
        print('-'*18,'Second Hero','-'*18)
        # Second Hero
        while True:
            n2 = input('Type  Your Second Hero\'s name: ')
            self.n2 = n2.capitalize()

            if self.n2.split():
                if self.n1 == self.n2:
                    print('\nOh! We have a hero by name',self.n2)
                    self.n2 = print('Change Second Hero\'s name: ')
                else:
                    break
            print('Invalid Hero\'s name\n')

    # just a random silly game
    def chance_game(self):
        win = ['Awesome','Bravo','You Rock']
        los = ['Next time', 'Almost won','Never quit']

        p1 = random.randint(1,10)
        p2 = random.randint(1,10)

        if p1 > p2:
            print(random.choice(win),self.n1)
            print(random.choice(los),self.n2)
        else:
            print(random.choice(win),self.n2)
            print(random.choice(los),self.n1)

# Initiate your intro
game = Hero()

# Use the variable else where e.g. chance game
game.chance_game()
```

stringValue.split() returns False if we have an empty input. The original condition will not catch double spaces ;)